# How can i decrypt byte[] of more than 16 bytes from AES

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, aes

So I have a byte[] with a length of 1622 bytes but I want to decrypt it all but AES has only a blocksize of 128 bits.
If im trying to split it up to blocks of 16 bytes i get this exception: 
**System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
Additional information: Input buffer contains insufficient data.** Can it be that ***rawDataArea % 16 != 0***?

Encryptor:

```
        aes256Alg = new AesManaged
        {
            Key = new byte[] {112,90,16,164,90,221,73,154,246,32,13,102,145,7,57,115,37,5,3,102,205,39,202,231,195,148,202,229,53,138,102,242},
            Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
            KeySize = 256,
            BlockSize = 128,
            Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
            IV = new byte[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
        };
        ICryptoTransform aes256Encryptor = aes256Alg.CreateEncryptor(aes256Alg.Key,aes256Alg.IV);
```

---

Decryptor

```
        AesManaged aes256AlgCBC;
        aes256AlgCBC = new AesManaged
        {
            Key = new byte[] {190,151,28,108,241,101,254,174,16,11,87,84,239,140,239,85,195,25,78,192,105,109,95,128,160,146,123,31,190,188,181,216},
            KeySize = 256,
            Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
            BlockSize = 128,
            Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
            IV = new byte[] {199,114,91,241,148,90,133,166,13,52,142,187,101,125,81,73}
        };
        ICryptoTransform aes256CbcDecryptor = aes256AlgCBC.CreateDecryptor(aes256AlgCBC.Key, aes256AlgCBC.IV);



        //byte[] rawDataArea = {0x00 .......} // Length of 1622 copied from hexeditor

        List<Byte[]> dataAreaByteList = new List<byte[]>();
       //Split the rawDataArea up to blocks of 16 bytes and then adding them to a list 
       //which later can be converted back to a big array

       for (int i = 0; i < rawDataArea.Length; i += 16)
       {
             byte[] transformedBlock = new byte[] { };
             aes128CbcDecryptor.TransformBlock(rawDataArea, i, (i += 16),transformedBlock,i);
             dataAreaByteList.Add(transformedBlock);
        }
```

Comment: The length of the byte array has to be a factor of 16. If it isn't, that's where padding comes into play.

Comment: If you want to use the `TransformBlock`-style interface, you need to use [`TransformFinalBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.icryptotransform.transformfinalblock(v=vs.110).aspx) on, well, the final block. It, specifically, allows for chunks of data that don't equal an entire block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're executing `i += 16` two times per loop iteration. You don't need to transform in 16 byte chunks anyway. Use `CryptoStream` and write any amount you like such as 4KB. Most tutorials do this. Maybe you found a bad tutorial.

Comment: Thanks, im now following a tutorial about it. I will upvote and accept if it works :)